# directory traversal in Java using regular and enhanced for loops

Tags: java

I have this code to print out all directories and files. I tried to use recursive method call in for loop. With enhanced for loop, the code prints out all the directories and files correctly. But with regular for loop, the code does not work. I am puzzled by the difference between regular and enhanced for loops.

```
public class FileCopy {

private File[] childFiles = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileCopy fileCopy = new FileCopy();
    File srcFile = new File("c:\\temp");                                    
    fileCopy.copyTree(srcFile);

}

public void copyTree(File file){

       if(file.isDirectory()){
         System.out.println(file + " is a directory. ");
         childFiles = file.listFiles();
         /*for(int j=0; j<childFiles.length; j++){
             copyTree(childFiles[j]);
         }*/                               //This regular for loop is not working
         for(File a: childFiles){
             copyTree(a);               //The enhanced for loop is working!
         }
         return;
       } else{
           System.out.println(file + " is a file. ");
           return;
       }
}
```

}

Comment: That's pretty surprising, as the two should compile down to the exact same bytecode... Are you sure that's the *only* thing you changed?

Comment: Why is `childFiles` shared? That's your *other* change isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the for loop, but your code.

When recursing you are incorrectly reassigning and reusing the shared variable

```
private File[] childFiles = null;
```

This should work now:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileCopy {

    /*private File[] childFiles = null;*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileCopy fileCopy = new FileCopy();
        File srcFile = new File("c:\\temp");                                    
        fileCopy.copyTree(srcFile);

    }

    public void copyTree(File file){
       if(file.isDirectory()){
         System.out.println(file + " is a directory. ");
         File[] childFiles = file.listFiles();           
         for(int j=0; j<childFiles.length; j++){
             copyTree(childFiles[j]);
         }                               //This regular for loop is now working
         /*for(File a: childFiles){
             copyTree(a);               //The enhanced for loop is working!
         }*/
       } else{
           System.out.println(file + " is a file. ");
       }
       return;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked. You are right that I should not use a class variable, which is shared and reused every time in the recursive calls. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

`childFiles` is a field. That means every call to `copyTree` with a directory as parameter changes the field value. The important difference in the for loops is:

`for(File a: childFiles)` always uses the initial `childFiles`, i.e. it is equivalent to

```
File[] temp = childFiles;
for(int j=0; j<temp.length; j++) {
    File a = temp[j];
    // for body from your code follows
    copyTree(a);
}
```

but `for(int j=0; j<childFiles.length; j++)` always uses the current value of the `childFiles` field, even if a new value (the files in the last subdirectory visited) was assigned.